# Spring MVC 3.0 , 404 Error , Controller used to serve Home page

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I want to route my application(Spring running on Apache Tomcat 7.0) on Startup/Launch to a Controller that serves a Home view

Therefore:

1)  I defined a index.htm in the welcome file tag in web.xml

2)  I annotated HomeController with 
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/index.htm")

3)  I also mapped HomeController in xml bean

---

My web.xml:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

---

Snippet of my spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"     
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<!-- Controller beab mappinh -->
   <bean class="com.yourmarketnet.controller.spring.HomeController" 
   name="HomeController"/>

    <bean id="unAuthenticatedUrlMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/index.htm">HomeController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

---

snippet from applicationContext.xml:

```
<!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes --> 
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.   For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package--> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.mvc.controller.spring" />    
    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.  Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  --> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />      
    <!-- mapping of static resources-->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />
```

---

My HomeController:

```
package com.yourmarketnet.controller.spring;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

       @Controller 
        @RequestMapping(value={"/","/index.htm"})
        //If have also tried RequestMapping("/index.htm") OR //If have also tried RequestMapping("index.htm")
        public class HomeController {

            @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String requestHandler()
            {
                return "Home"; 
            }
        }
```

This is also my project structure:

[image]

### However

Im getting 404 Error on application launch "The requested resource () is not available."

Answer (score 0):

Try doing context-component scan of your controller .

Add the following line in your ..-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller.spring"/>
```

Comment: With the above configuration you will not have to explicitly define the homecontroller bean and url mapping. Spring will automatically register the definitions

Comment: The component scan tag is actually already present in my applictaionContext.xml

Comment: I removed the index.htm ,and decided to go with redirect.jsp which sends redirect to HomeController.
After inspecting the Apache log, it seems that my controller “HomeController” is not being mapped using for example mapping “/HomeController” or any other mapping: `package com.yourmarketnet.controller;
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("/HomeController") 
public class HomeController {
public String requestHandler()
{ 
return "Home"; 
} 
}   
`
It seems although I have  `<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller" />` , THE MAPPING IS JUST NOT REGISTERING.Thanks.

Comment: By the way I changed my package structure to com.yourmarketnet.controller so the <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller" /> is correct

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is your index.htm in the project structure??

And you can not define the **index.htm** both as a welcome-file and map it with the controller.

You have two solutions.

1. If you have no use of index.htm then remove it completely from the welcome-file-list and then map your controller only with **"/"** value.
2. Or you can make index.htm as only the mapping in your controller without using **"/"** mapping also. And don't use any welcome-file-list.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: I tried both methods , however I noticed this , WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/yourmarketnet/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'yourmarketnet'                          Although it actually is see : `<servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Comment: Adding the servlet name in your web.xml for spring's dispatcher servlet is not the mapping. You should have the root as your project name. The one you have not displayed in the project strcture. Try using your project name as the root path.

Comment: I added the root as the project name see beloew: `<servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name> <url-pattern>yourmarketnet/</url-pattern>` which caused another exception that crashed Apache Tomcat :Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> yourmarketnet/ in servlet mapping

Comment: I also tried `<servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/yourmarketnet/*</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>` AND `<servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>yourmarketnet</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/yourmarketnet/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping> ` Although the illegal url mapping exception went away Im still getting 404 Error "The requested resource (/yourmarketnet/) is not available.
"

Comment: No no... You are totally on wrong track buddy.

There is no change required in the servlet mapping you have defined in your web.xml. You need to change the way you are mapping the index.htm both in the controller and welcome-file-list. There can be anyone of them.

Comment: Please clarify , "in simple code", given code and structure that I have provided above, what should the mappings be in all required files. Basically what should my web.xml look like, what should my spring-servlet.xml look like, what should my HomeController look like, exactly, finally, and in conclusion. Thanks.

Comment: I removed the index.htm ,and decided to go with redirect.jsp which sends redirect to HomeController.
After inspecting the Apache log, it seems that my controller “HomeController” is not being mapped using for example mapping “/HomeController” or any other mapping: `package com.yourmarketnet.controller;
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("/HomeController") 
public class HomeController {
public String requestHandler()
{ 
return "Home"; 
} 
}   
`
It seems although I have  `<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller" />` , THE MAPPING IS JUST NOT REGISTERING.Thanks.

Comment: By the way I changed my package structure to com.yourmarketnet.controller so the <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller" /> is correct

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
@Controller 
public class HomeController {
            @RequestMapping({"/"})
            public String requestHandler()
            {
                return "Home"; 
            }
        }
```

You're all set.

You don't need the

```
<bean id="unAuthenticatedUrlMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/index.htm">HomeController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

If you're using annotations.

Comment: I removed the index.htm ,and decided to go with redirect.jsp which sends redirect to HomeController.
After inspecting the Apache log, it seems that my controller “HomeController” is not being mapped using for example mapping “/HomeController” or any other mapping: `package com.yourmarketnet.controller;
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("/HomeController") 
public class HomeController {
public String requestHandler()
{ 
return "Home"; 
} 
}   
`
It seems although I have  `<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller" />` , THE MAPPING IS JUST NOT REGISTERING.Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the component scan path is correct? In your question, the component scan base package is different from what you've stated above.

Comment: By the way I changed my package structure to com.yourmarketnet.controller so the <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourmarketnet.controller" /> is correct

Comment: Hi @Varun i am running into same situation badly, could you please help me out on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697899/how-to-map-dynamic-url-prj-noticeopen-2-in-spring-mvc-controller